I want to show standard report on LWC component. Is there any way to achieve this using report id?
I would like to show Salesforce Standard Reports on LWC Component. Is there any way I can achieve it by passing Report ID or any other workaround?

To my knowledge, you can't display the report directly in a LWC. But here's what you can do:

Have a matrix or summary report with a chart.

Have a Visualforce page:


<analytics:reportChart reportId="[ID of report]" />


Have a LWC with this markup:

<iframe src="/apex/[name of Visualforce page]" 
    style="width: 100%; height: 50rem"></iframe>

